# Firebase BigQuery, get event_name before 'app_remove' is triggered

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

So in Biquery with the source of Firebase Analytics.
You have the event "app_remove"

The following displays the users_pseudo_id's and the timestamp when they removed the app.

```
SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp   FROM `private-4cb88.analytics_184376442.events_20200324` where event_name LIKE "%app_remove%" LIMIT 100
```

The data I want is the previous event_name from those user_pseudo_id.

How can I get the event_names before (app_remove timestamp) that user app_remove? So I can understand what the last event was before they removed the app.

I have been trying for days now, I really need some help.

The result I want is a table, with each userid, previous event_name and timestamp of that event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use window functions:

```
select user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp
from (
    select
        r.*,
        lead(event_name) over(partition by user_pseudo_id order by event_timestamp) lead_event_name
    from `private-4cb88.analytics_184376442.events_20200324` r 
) t
where lead_event_name like '%app_remove%'
limit 100
```

Comment: Great thanks! Is there a way I can "go back" 2 or 3 events before "app_remove"?

Comment: @Sharpless512: just `lead(event_name, 2)`, or `lead(event_name, 3)`

Comment: @GMB thanks for the awesome query. I am using `lead(event_name, 3)` to go 3 events back and want to group the data by `user_pseudo_id` so that I can sort the data with the most common 3 events pattern. The intention is to find out the most common event that most users did before uninstalling the app. I'll be using Data Studio on the data. But grouping by `user_pseudo_id` is not helping. Can you please guide?

Comment: @LittleLebowski: probably in this case you would group by `event_name` instead?